# iosアプリでのローカル通知の実装方法

Tags: ios, monaca

現在monacaを用いてiosアプリの開発を行っています。
作成しているアプリでローカル通知(画面上部に数秒現れる通知）を実装したいので調べていたのですがプッシュ通信の実装しか見つけることが出来ない状態です。
どのように書けばローカル通知を実現できるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

以下のCordova Local-Notification PluginをCordovaPlugin管理から追加してください。

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/

プラグインの詳細な使い方はこちらにExampleが用意されていますので利用してみるとわかりやすいと思います。

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/11.-Samples

Comment: ありがとうございます。
試してみようと試みたのですがmonacaの無料プランでは公開されているCordovaプラグインを組み込むことが出来ないようなのでプランを変更するなり開発環境を変更することを検討しようと思います。